# Map a function with more than one argument

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, google-earth-engine

I have a function that I would like to map over an image collection:

```
var moisture = function (img, driest, wettest){
  var img = img.clip(table).select('VV')
  var sensitivity = wettest.subtract(driest); 
  var SMmax=0.32; 
  var SMmin=0.05;
  var calculateSSM = function (image){ return image.addBands(((image.subtract(driest)).divide(sensitivity))
  .multiply(SMmax-SMmin).add(SMmin)); }; 
  var ssm = calculateSSM(img) 
  var ssm = ssm.select('VV_1').rename('moisture');
  return ssm}

var coll2014 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT') 
  .filterBounds(table) 
  .filterDate('2014-08-15','2014-12-31')
  .map(function (img) {return ee.Image(img).log10().multiply(10.0)});
  
var dry2014 = coll2014.min()
var wet2014 = coll2014.max()
```

How can I pass `driest` and `wettest`?
I tryed

```
var add = moisture.bind (null, dry2014, wet2014)
var moisture2014 = coll2014.map(add)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Or, even better, is there a way to define dry2014 and wet2014 inside the function?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the 1st and 2nd arguments, but `driest` and `wettest` are the 2nd and 3rd arguments. There is no way to skip arguments when using `bind()`.

So use an anonymous function with `map()`

```
var moisture2014 = coll2014.map(fuction(img) { 
    return moisture(img, dry2014, wet2014); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, maybe I am missing something or there is a different syntax in GEE. [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/72986cef06e1badb29c68a6e4064a74e)
I get a SyntaxError

Comment: That link doesn't work for me because I don't have an Earth Engine account.

Comment: Use traditional function syntax instead of an arrow function. `function(img) { return moisture(img, dry2014, wet2014); }`

Comment: The token '=>' does not exist. This is not applied on gee.

Comment: @Lotte I've updated the answer to use traditional function syntax.